# Creating own Amazon Machine Image - Kernel panic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have created own AMI and registered it on Amazon EC2.
But while AMI startup I receive following error:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)

The image is running locally without any problems.

fstab contains:

```
proc          /proc   proc     defaults                      0 0
/dev/sda1     /       ext3     relatime,errors=remount-ro    0 1
```

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering the AMI with correct AKI and ARI. 
Do not use default ARI and AKI. Find the original on http://thecloudmarket.com